# Consuming restful API with vue js

Tags: api, vue.js

I want to use Vue is CDN only because the command line thing isn't really my thing. Including the Vue js cdn to login authenticate on my frontend webpage by consuming API values from my restful API be possible?

Comment: There isn't much command line required for Vue or authentication. What are you using for authentication, jwt?

Comment: Not using jwt sir .  My backend API is built with codeigniter.   I want this method using just CDN and not CLI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is how you would setup a basic Vue app in a single html file. The problem is that your template has to be written as a string which is harder to work with than using .vue files.

https://jsfiddle.net/ellisdod/w2pskga4/1/

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>

<script>
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: function(){
    return {
      message: 'My App',
      userData : null,
      }
  },
  methods : {
    getLoggedInContent () {
      // call rest API
      const apiData = 'User 1' 
      this.userData = apiData
    }
  },
  template : `
  <div>
  <h2> {{message}} </h2>
  <button @click="getLoggedInContent"> Sign In </button>
  <p v-if="userData"> {{userData}} </p>
  </div>
  `,
  })
</script>
```

Comment: That wasn't the answer I wanted . But yes I figured everything after a bit of research